# SVG line between circles (animation)

Tags: jquery, svg, line, geometry, between

I am trying to create an animation in SVG with SnapSVG but I'm stuck on one thing.

I've created a particul effect as you can see on this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/km00bu0o/

Now i'm trying to draw a line between two particle.
This line must appear when there is less than 100 pixels gap between two particles.

I've tryed with this but le navigateur bug ..

```
      for(i = 0; i < numberParticules; i++){
          for(j = 0; j < numberParticules; j++){

              var iParticule = stockParticules[i];
              var jParticule = stockParticules[j];

              var posXI = parseFloat(iParticule.attr('cx'));
              var posYI = parseFloat(iParticule.attr('cy'));
              var posXJ = parseFloat(jParticule.attr('cx'));
              var posYJ = parseFloat(jParticule.attr('cy'));

              proximity = 100;

              if(
                    (posXI - posXJ) < proximity &&
                    (posYI - posYJ) < proximity &&
                    (posXJ - posXI) > - proximity &&
                    (posYJ - posYI) > - proximity
              ) {
                      var line = s.line(posXI, posYI, posXJ, posYJ).attr({stroke: '#a6a8ab', strokeWidth: '1px'});
              }

              else if(
                    (posXI - posXJ) < proximity &&
                    (posYI - posYJ) < proximity &&
                    (posXJ - posXI) > - proximity &&
                    (posYJ - posYI) > - proximity
              )
              {
                    var lines = s.selectAll('line');
                    lines.remove();
              }

          }
      }
```

This part of code is inserted in animationParticules function ..

To sum up, the lines are drawn but the "100 pixels" proximity is not considered and the line does not disappear above 100 pixels ..

Have you got any solution ?

Comment: can you please also add the JSFiddle where you tried to add the lines?

Comment: Sure ! http://jsfiddle.net/km00bu0o/1/

Comment: wow, this is freezing my browser :(

Comment: yes :( i've certainly forget conditions .. ^^

Comment: Firstly I'd use `Math.abs(posXI - posXJ) < proximity`. Secondly, your fiddle freezes the browser.